# In which thread do functions live that are called by QThread's run method?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

It is quite clear from the Qt documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) that subclassing QThread is no longer the recommended way of using multi-threading (instead you should create a QObject and move it to another thread) as the `run` method is the only thing living in the new thread when subclassing.

However, I have a number of old projects subclassing QThread, which are running fine, but after reading the QThread doc I wonder in which thread functions are being executed that are called inside QThread’s `run` method.

To make it more clear, here is an example code:

helperThread.h:

```
#ifndef HELPERTHREAD_H
#define HELPERTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>

class helperThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    helperThread();
    ~helperThread();

    void memberFunc();
    void run() override;

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &s);
};

#endif // HELPERTHREAD_H
```

helperThread.cpp:

```
#include "helperthread.h"

helperThread::helperThread()
{
    this->start();
}

helperThread::~helperThread()
{

}

void noMemberFunc()
{
    // this static function is no member of helperThread
    // some code
}

void helperThread::memberFunc()
{
    // this function is a member of helperThread
    // some code
}

void helperThread::run()
{
    noMemberFunc(); // in which thread is this function living?
    memberFunc(); // and in which thread is this func living?

    QString result = "result...";
    emit resultReady(result);
}
```

As far as I understand, `helperThread` and all its methods excluding `run` live in the old thread (in my case just the MainWindow), while the code inside `run` is executed in a new thread, so that it doesn’t block the old one.

However, I put two functions inside the `run` method in the above example (a member function and a non-member function).

Are they executed in the new thread (that of `run`) and thus not blocking my main thread, or are they executed in the old thread (and thus blocking it)?

And is there any command to test in which thread I am currently?

Comment: A function does not live in any thread. A function is a description of what has to be done. If you call a function it will do that task within the thread it is called.

Comment: Your `run` method runs on the new QThread. Any objects you allocate in the dynamic scope of that method will have the QThread as owner.

Comment: @t.niese Understood, many thanks! Also thanks to Botje!

Comment: And if you want to test you can always sprinkle some qDebug << Qthread::currentThread() which will print out the currently executing thread